# Can I prevent hazardous medicine leaving my body from entering the biosphere?

Tags: waste

I read a lot about the amount of medicine found in the environment is ever increasing. This attributes to resistance to antibiotics for example.

Can these chemicals be prevented from entering the environment.

And which medicines are most harmful?

(Not sure if I should split this question)

Comment: This does seem overly broad at the moment - I don't think a single answer could cover all possible medicines.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers is correct. Also, some sewage goes to a septic drain field, while other wastewater goes to the open ocean, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** no

**Longer answer:** Yes, if you bag your body up in some sort of non-porous plastic to prevent it from excreting any fluid or solid wastes.

*Alternative question:* what changes, if any, should I make in my med use to reduce the amount of bio contamination? (list meds here)